# Fortran .exe's no longer "self-contained"?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran

I use a small in-house cluster (approx. 31 machines) to help complete parallel runs of a numerical groundwater model.  After the groundwater model completes, a short post-processor manipulates some data for use by a code that is collecting output from the parallel runs.  It used to be that the post-processor, written in fortran and compiled using intel's visual fortran from inside Vis. Studio 2010, was distribute-able, meaning I could place the .exe in amongst the other files that were distributed across the cluster and run on the various machines.  Now, however, if I compile the very same fortran using visual studio 2012 with Intel Fortran XE 2013, I get an error on the cluster machines stating, "The program can't start because MSVCRR110.dll is missing from your computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix this probelm."

One of the reasons I like using Fortran is that it used to be self-contained.  In other words, if I wrote small programs to do some short pithy task in another language, say R or Python, then I have to either install these programs on all the cluster machines or else "sandbox" the programs in with my distributed files.  Forget about trying to use C# or VB etc., because then the cluster machines would need to have .NET framework installed.  For the time being I can go back and use VS2010 to compile, but I don't anticipate having this option available to me much longer.  Is there another alternative for keeping fortran programs "self-contained" in VS2012?  As you can see in the code below, nothing complicated and no reason for it not be a self-contained executable:

```
program Calc_Seep

implicit none

! Variables
integer       reason
real          wp,time,ft,fts,fr,fo,fst,fro,loss1,loss2,loss3
character (len=120) line
character*50  txt
character*20  fmt

wp = 9.38              !a needed constant value
!read(*,*) txt
open(5,file='balance.out') 
read(5,'(A)') line

do while (.NOT.line.EQ.'')
    read(5,'(A)',IOSTAT=Reason) line
    if (Reason < 0) exit
end do

read(line,*)  time,ft,fts,fr,fo,fst,fro

!acre-ft/mi/yr
loss1 = (ft/time)*0.3048*5280*208*24/(0.3048**3)/43560.17
!ft/day
loss2 = (ft/time)*24/(0.3048**2)/wp
!cfs/mi
loss3 = (ft/time)*24/(0.3048**2)*5280/86400

close(5)

!now write the processed values to a file
open(5,file="Seepage.out")
write(5,'(A)') "acre-ft/mi/yr       ft/day       cfs/mi"
write(5,100) loss1, loss2, loss3
100 format(3f13.6)
close(5)

end program Calc_Seep
```

Comment: it's not that hard to install the visual C runtime on each machine. but most likely you're not compiling a "static" app anymore, which would stuff any "external" libraries directly into the exe.

Comment: Just copy the run-time libraries with the program or compile with `-static` or `-static-intel`.

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a change in default project properties for newly created projects. As of Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 2013 SP1 (compiler version 14), the default is to link against the DLL libraries, matching what MS Visual C++ does. Existing projects are not affected and you can still change the libraries setting (Fortran > Libraries > Runtime Library) to "Multithreaded" from "Multithreaded DLL". If you do that, then it will again link to the static libraries, though there are some libraries provided only in DLL form (OpenMP and coarray support).

Comment: I'm having this same issue and it's not solved with the Multithread option.

I have two projects in a solution. One is a DLL and the other a console application. I've correctly set the compilation dependencies and the "Link Library Dependencies" option to "Yes". Both projects compile and link correctly as Multithreaded (/libs:static) but when I run the project it asks for the .dll file.

Comment: You also asked this in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler/topic/848750 where I pointed out that the .LIB created when you build a DLL is not a static library but rather an "import library, used to tell the EXE how to find the DLL.